# Where can I view the user with the most questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Where can I view the user who has asked the most questions? Kind of like the leaderboard for most answers.

Comment: There's a leaderboard for the person with the most answers...?

Comment: I guess I meant the [top score](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). One would assume that anyone on that list has a bunch of answers more so than questions.

Comment: [Who asked the most number of questions on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284601/who-asked-the-most-number-of-questions-on-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Top Askers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1251/top-askers-with-score) on SE Data Explorer:

The top asker is [Blankman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39677) who had **1371** at the last data dump (March 21, 2011)

However, you can see that the top asker by `SUM(Score)` is [Karan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11110/karan), almost entirely by [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books), followed closely by [Edward Tanguay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639/edward-tanguay) with **2338** over 955 questions.

I don't know about a leaderboard for *most* answers, but here is a [query for that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1252/most-prolific-answerers-with-score) too — as we all know, Jon Skeet is the most prolific answerer by far.

Comment: I was thinking that http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all was a representation of the number of answers, but it's just overall points not answers.

Comment: That's pretty cool that they let anyone write queries against their database.

Comment: @guanome: It's not the database but the data _dump_ which is created every one or two months.

Comment: @hendrik-vogt That's smart

Comment: karan's answer is long time gone (deleted), so their `sum(score)` is now quite little