# Centralized page for information on daily limits

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, daily-reputation-limit, voting-limits

Can we have some tool/page that shows:

- How many up/downvotes we have given and how many are left
- Same thing with close votes
- Same thing with moderator attention flags
- *And perhaps...* How many rep. points we can earn before reaching the cap (taking in consideration accepts and bounties, of course)
- And finally, how much time is left until the SO day is over and these limits are reset

I don't know if I missed any limits... I left out the [50 questions a month limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) because I don't think there are many people who get that.

Comment: There's a daily limit on delete votes, and suggested edit review votes too.