# Unable to ask more than 50 questions in a 30 day period?

Tags: support, monthly-question-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [50 question per month limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)

Stack Overflow does not allow me to ask any further questions!

Despite logging in, verifying my email address etc.

The message I get:

> Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period.

Please fix.

Comment: When you are not allowed, a reason is given. Did you read the reason? What did it say? Did you correct your question accordingly?

Comment: And what happens when you try to ask a Question?

Comment: I'm noticing that this question is also not a question....could be related to the issues on the main site.

Comment: @DaveShaw He fails ... I guess.

Answer (score 4):

When you try to ask a question, it tells you to go to a link. http://goo.gl/C1Kwu <-- the link, just in case you can't find it.

Read what it says on the link. But I'll explain anyway: the website automatically IP bans people with a bad question rating history, and you won't be able to ask questions (ever) unless you spend some time giving good answers and improving your account.

---

Edit: After you posted a comment on my answer telling me what the error message was: "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: •Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period"

Well after doing some research, I have come to the conclusion problem is that you've asked more than 50 questions in a 30 day period.

Comment: Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: •Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period.

Comment: I also noticed you made a new account. You should include the name of the account that you cannot ask questions on in this question.