# How long does the 50 questions limit last?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, rate-limiting

I got the [50 questions limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) message.

How long does this probation lasts?

Thanks

Comment: It's not a probation, as far as I know it's for *all* users, network-wide.

Comment: Ok,I just was wondering how long does this global limit last

Comment: I beleive it's 50 questions, a month, for the lifetime of you account, no exceptions. I don't have a source though. Because, really, 50 questions is *a lot*. The only way to get around it is to create another account (but don't do that, because the filters will pick it up and auto-merge the accounts, plus you'd face sanctions).

Comment: I was wondering when it resets.

Comment: @user155461 - for info on when it "resets", see the italicised part of my answer. That said, it doesn't reset back to "0", rather the questions that you asked on the day that's now 31 days ago no longer count towards your limit of 50 questions =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the limit is based on a rolling 30 day period. So, if you've asked 1 question 30 days ago and another 49 over the other 29 of the 30 days, as of tomorrow you'll be able to ask another question.

*Bear in mind that the stackexchange day runs from midnight UTC (aka GMT) so the new day will start when midnight ticks over in London, UK.*

Comment: Also note that deleting a question won't do any good.

Comment: True; but then deleting a question doesn't remove the fact that you've still *asked* a question =) If I've bought 10 pies, eating one doesn't mean I've bought 9 pies because only 9 are still visible. Mmmmh, pie!

Comment: don't you mean waffles? ;)

Comment: No, I mean pie. If I'd meant waffles there would have been gratuitous mention of salted caramel icecream and other such essentials (I also meant pie in its UK guise where it's mainly used in the generic form to refer to savoury pies, rather than desert pies). =)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to wait until the first of those questions drop out of the 30 day window. It's not a ban, just a limitation.