# How many questions are too many?

Tags: discussion, questions

As part of my new year's resolution, I want to try to really get better and much more advanced at a certain technology (Mathematica). I learn best by just doing things and as such, I end up having a ton of random questions. StackExchange seems like a great place to ask these questions and have people answer them .. but I could have up to a question per day. Is this too many questions? Is there a question:answer ratio that users should try to comply with, just as a matter of decorum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best gauge for the future lies within [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/168244):

> ### Asking
>
> - Users < 125 rep, 20 minutes (90 minutes on [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256323/questions-are-now-rate-limited-to-1-per-90-minutes))
>
>   - Users limited by [Anti-Recidivism System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/168244), one question per week
>   - Users limited from asking questions for 1 - 7 days [based on the performance of their previous questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)
> - Users < 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 60 seconds
> - Users > 10k rep trip Captcha if more than once per 30 seconds
> - On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Math (not active on all other sites)
>
>   - maximum of 6 questions per day
>   - [maximum of 50 questions per 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/168244)

In terms of post quality... that's up to the community.

Answer (score 7):

If you are asking useful, constructive, non-duplicate, and well-written questions, there is no such thing as "too many."