# Deadlock for question-banned users. What solution does the system offer?

Tags: support, post-ban, ban

I know the question-ban system was recently revised to help users who got stuck in ban but have the potential to progress.

[What is the reasoning behind limiting "recidivists" to post one question per week?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234609/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-limiting-recidivists-to-post-one-question-per-wee/234610#234610)

But as a question-banned user for more than three months, I don't know how to benefit from this policy, I asked a similar question on StackOverflow but yet received no answer.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284017/how-can-a-currently-banned-user-benefit-from-the-rate-limit-policy-for-questions

As I understood [from this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274417/my-account-been-banned-from-asking-questions-how-can-i-delete-my-account/274421#274421), I need to delete my current account and create a new account to have the chance of asking one question per week; However, I am a question-banned user not answer-banned, I don't know whether my questions will be deleted or both questions and answers!

By the way I tried to improve my questions but for some reasons I think the mechanism for reevaluation them is absent or weak or slow (or maybe I don't know it?). Specially if the questions be neutral (neither bad nor good) improving them doesn't gain much votes (few are above 4, most have zero score and the score of other ones varies between +1 and -1!). If that is the only way to leave the ban then I can figure out **a deadlock** situation for such users.

Meanwhile I tried to answer questions (76 so far) and help the site by flagging and editing, however I am not sure how much they are effective to leave a question-ban.

I don't know if it's a good idea to restate my questions [in the previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284017/how-can-a-currently-banned-user-benefit-from-the-rate-limit-policy-for-questions) here or not, but since I need to get an answer for them, I am asking them here:

> I would like to use the chance of asking one question per week, yet use my current credentials. So if
>   this is an option, how can I make use of it?
>
> Beside, I don't know why they mentioned this option, but if it is a
>   chance for a banned user, is it possible that they provide it without
>   the need to create another account? And Is it possible that I keep
>   some of my current questions or answers?
>
> Generally, what does the system offer to users who got stuck in the
>   ban prior the time of applying new policies? How can they benefit from
>   the new policies?

Comment: +1 for asking nicely, but I fear there's no deadlock or hellbanning in Stack Exchange. Just keep answering, harvest votes, and at some point the ban will be lifted.

Comment: Wow, you read an answer that starts "we recommend not deleting your account", and your conclusion is that you need to delete your account?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Yes that's a recommendation which I also liked to follow, but I after 3 months I see myself in a deadlock situation, then I thought of the other option to use one question per week. it says to have this chance one should delete his account!

Comment: It is so nice to see someone asking nicely instead of all the rants and debates we get from some other new users. Thank you.

Comment: @Camil http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2651073/ahmad?tab=questions

Comment: @CamilStaps About the InfiniteRecursion link, lol, Yes, I feel I myself was a little on the ranty side out of frustration, however there were some points in my posts. Here as I posted it, I was waiting to be bombarded with down-votes again, but now I feel language and a bit tolerance helps (much!).

Answer (score 11):

There's a bit of an overlapping circle that you were caught in. First, you're no longer blocked, congratulations! I wouldn't consider anything in your history to be particularly horrible - writing with haste seems to be what catches you.

Second - we *did* overhaul the system considerably, however, you were in the throes of the final (more aggressive) block by the time that we did. This means, you did not benefit from being slowed down by rolling rate limits and shown additional help as you approached them. That help has made a pretty phenomenal impact on those that *can* be helped, and you're squarely in that bracket.

Had you [contacted us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), we probably would have disassociated one of your negatively-scored posts from your account to lift the block, as it's quite clear that you are a positive contributor and have been working diligently on improving what you're already giving us for free :) The only time we *discourage* participation now is when someone has a clear track record of contributing things that actively drive people away, despite being shown a lot of additional help and slowed down considerably.

Just take your time, proof read your posts, take any opportunity to expand the depth of your answers and really *teach* when you have mastery of the subject at hand, and continue putting thought into your questions prior to asking them.

tl;dr; - Had the new system been in place when you started, you probably would not have ever encountered the block, as you're obviously capable of benefiting from the additional help that we provide. In cases like this, we're *usually* inclined to help out if we can.

Comment: Thank you very much for your consideration. About the contact us, I actually had contacted the site, and they replied "We cannot lift posting blocks - you must improve your existing posts in order for the system to allow you to participate further.". Anyway, thank you again; I try to enhance my skills and contribute effectively to the site.

Answer (score 8):

I looked at your recent answers and to be honest they are OK-ish. But some need some love from you.

For example one with a SQL query, why don't you provide a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with it to make it stand out from the other answer?

Other answers can use a link to the MSDN documentation or explanation to make them more than just a *here is the solution/`code block`* post.

One answer was simply a link to another answer. I realize you are desperate but that kind of *answer* isn't worth an upvote.

Some of your answers are on old questions. Why don't you try to answer recent questions?  C#, java, php are highly active tags and you have a risk to face the [Fastest Gun In the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem but if you filter on a [subtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+winforms) you find that the questions come in at a lower rate and give you more time to prepare an excellent answer and still be the first. That would raise the chance of your answer being accepted.

In regard to your flags, check your [flag history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2651073) to see how you are doing.

I see you are suggesting edits which is good. Your last suggested edit got  rejected, don't try to think for the OP and add by yourself what the OP missed. See also [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252806/when-should-i-edit-something-vs-comment-on-it-if-its-a-relatively-trivial-error) that advises against adding or changing code in posts.

I have no idea how far away you are from being unbanned. Keep answering, suggesting good edits...if this isn't good advice I'm sure a Community Manager or Moderator will correct me.

Comment: Thank you, actually I wasn't sure answering questions will help me to leave the question ban. Beside, I think my questions may don't gain much votes; if that's a precondition, maybe answers won't help me too. Wish you would consider some suggestion on my current questions too. However thank you for your suggestion on answering questions.

Comment: About my last suggesting edit you mentioned, actually the code was offered by the OP himself but in comments! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253429/how-to-write-a-paragraph-in-arabic-in-html/28253555?noredirect=1#comment44866206_28253555, I thought to move this code to the question, something that the OP had to do. I didn't add it by myself. However thank you for the hint.

Comment: Just let the OP edit his own code as [explaned on MSO here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252806/when-should-i-edit-something-vs-comment-on-it-if-its-a-relatively-trivial-error)