# Are migrations allowed if the user is banned on the destination site, but their 6-month limit has opened up?

Tags: support, migration, post-ban, migration-block

If a user is banned from asking on a given site, the system [will block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) migrations to that site of questions by the same user posted on different sites.

Additionally, the system [allows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) question-banned users to ask one question on the site every six months, to give them another shot at getting out of the ban.

Putting these pieces of information together, there is one thing that's unclear: if a user is, for example, banned on site A but it's been more than six months since they last asked a question (and so they are temporarily allowed one question), they ask a question on site B, and site B migrates it to site A, will the migration be allowed, since the user is (temporarily) allowed to ask there, or will it still be blocked since the user is banned on site A (regardless of the 6-month allowance)?

The team has stated that migrations are [only blocked if they would cause the rate limit to be exceeded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/377214), but I'm not sure if it applies to bans (i.e. the 6-month limit), only to the short rate limits that happen in advance of a ban.

Comment: Users are not recommended to post potentially off-topic stuff unless it legitimately belongs well in multiple sites. Migrations are rare exceptional events.

Comment: @MulliganReinstatingMonica I know; I've written most of the migration FAQ's current text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this case](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/where-should-questions-about-chatgpt-troubleshooting-be-asked-on-stack-exchange), the answer appears to be yes. The author there asked a question on Meta Web Applications while being banned on this site, and their last question here was asked more than a year ago so their limit was thus open, and it was migrated here successfully (and then rejected afterwards).

As to whether this is a deliberate design decision or just an accident of how the system is configured, I'm going to guess it's the latter, based on the fact that [the system doesn't let question-banned users whose 6-month limit has opened up about their ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361877/let-question-banned-users-know-that-theyre-banned-even-if-their-6-month-limit-h), which leads me to believe that the limit is implemented by a simple check that disables the ban for users whose last question was asked more than 6 months ago, so as far as the system knows such users are not banned.

Comment: You're welcome ;)