# Question Ban page has no formatting on SO and is rendered as gibberish on RU.SO

Tags: bug, design, post-ban, russian-stackoverflow

The situation is this: I asked the wrong question on https://stackoverflow.com, after which I received a ban on asking questions (I am not appealing the decision). But the ban itself looks strange.

[image]

I think it's strange, because there's just text on the page, and there aren't any styles. There's just naked text.

But on https://ru.stackoverflow.com the situation is even more strange. I asked a question, after which I received a warning that my questions were of poor quality and a ban on publication for one day (the block was supposed to be lifted today). But instead, when I clicked on the "ask a question" button, I got this:

[image]

What is this is related?

Comment: hm, I wonder if something's getting blocked, and the "wierd" text is misformed russian.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, Well, I don't know what is blocked, but it's strange. On https://stackoverflow.com I have one question in general, and that one with a positive reputation. Yes argue with the fact that I asked the wrong question on https://ru.stackoverflow.com I won't, but I honestly waited until the time of the "ban" has passed, and I had a question and when I try to ask it, I see these strange symbols.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I found out what is written in that incomprehensible text with https://ru.stackoverflow.com , thanks to the developer console(F12). It says there, this is "You have repeatedly asked low-quality questions. Please take more time and effort to think about it. To make this task easier, we have limited the number of questions you can ask in a week. For more information, please refer to" (I translated the text for convenience), but as I said, the "ban" with RUSO was supposed to fall off today, and I have only one question on it (yes, with a negative reputation in -1).

Comment: Oh I don't mean account level, I mean something in between you and Stack Exchange is manging responses.

Comment: I'm gonna guess someone lost a template and these are being served without a content type header.

Comment: At the time you asked this, your asking questions on Stack Overflow was *rate limited*, rather than banned. There's a significant difference. That status may have changed, but is only updated when you try to post a question, so I'm only guessing at that. The question rate limit was limiting you to asking one question per week, at least on Stack Overflow. If you were banned from asking questions, then it would be one every six months. Both the question rate limit and question ban are automatically imposed by the system. Moderators have no ability to directly control those rate limits or bans.

Comment: @Makyen,good remarks. But as I wrote here in my opinion, I asked only one question, after which I received such a "ban" (the question was with a positive reputation on SO). But we are not here for this, but to understand why when I click on the "Ask a question" button, I get a page without styles (in the case of SO) or even some nonsense (in the case of RU.SO ).

Comment: Most likely you have at least one other question on SO, which you asked before the visible one you meant, and it was deleted while having negative, or even 0, score. The fact a question is deleted does not make it vanish as if it never existed. It's still linked to  your account and affect it. You can see them by clicking "deleted questions" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current) which is in your profile.

Comment: @Shadow The GPT Wizard, you also have a very good and important comment on my claims, I didn't know that. But this does not apply to me, because. I have no deleted questions (sorry I can't attach a screenshot). And at the time of solving this question, I had only one question on SO, and it had a reputation of +1

Comment: So the only other possible thing is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234609/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-limiting-recidivists-to-post-one-question-per-wee/234610#234610). It limits asking questions to exactly what you described, once per week.