# Dozens of downvoted questions, yet they still have question privileges

Tags: discussion, down-votes, post-ban

Is there anything that can be done about users who have dozens of downvoted questions yet still seem to have asking privileges?

I know its an edge case, but I've seen a few users who seem to have an unreasonably large number of downvoted questions and/or an awful lot of closed questions who still have the ability to ask new questions.

It seems they get away with it because they've asked hundreds of questions all together, so they manage to ask enough "tolerable" questions to balance out the awful questions and they slide under the auto ban.

Should the automatic question ban be adjusted?
Are these cases that a moderator could handle?
Or am I just being overly critical?

Comment: There's no way we have any idea what you're talking about without an example.

Comment: @Doorknob I was under the impression that naming names is frowned on... I could, but I'm not sure that I should.

Comment: A few dozen out of hundreds means that over 75% of their questions are at least "not bad"...

Comment: @Servy I see your point, but where does one draw the line?

Comment: @apaul34208 Well, it's hard without seeing an example.  It would appear that the line has been drawn at some point that the user has not yet crossed.

Comment: Somewhat related discussion at [50 question per month limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217) regarding Blankman, considered by some [to be a supervillain of asking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit#comment221555_89217).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Its definitely more than somewhat related... but Blankman isn't the only one who has a nefarious approach to asking questions.

Comment: True enough; I can think of two users off the top of my head that I've seriously considered flagging as Robert describes.

Answer (score 9):

If a user has a pattern of asking low-quality questions that is troublesome enough to consider for moderator attention, flag one of their posts, and ask for a moderator review.

There are a number of reasons why this can happen.  Some tags get answer upvotes because they are frequented by a high percentage of folks who think the questions are good.  Sometimes sock puppets are involved, or coworkers who upvote just because they are a coworker or friend.  Moderators can deal with these issues if there is an ongoing pattern of marginal behavior.

Comment: How does one go about flagging these cases? Is it as simple as "Hey take a long look at this users list of questions..."

Comment: Also what is the official stance on naming specific users in these issues here on Meta? It seems there's a lot of requests for a specific reference.

Comment: now that we have the ability to respond to flags without declining them, your best bet is to actually flag this user's post, and tell us why you're flagging, and what actionable thing you want to come from it. In this case, it's a system imposed ban, so the best we can do is say, "We'll take it to the SE team and ask them if they need to adjust their algorithm." We know there are ineffeciencies with the ban algorithm, but it's up to @shog9 et. al., to address them.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I just flagged one. I guess I'll see how it goes

Comment: Beyond people using sock puppets or voting rings, the most common cases of this that I've seen are users who have accounts that predate the question ban. Before that point, they spammed enough questions that some fraction got upvoted, enough that they'd never get banned again. In a few of these cases, we've had to step in and manually suspend the user to stop them from asking any more questions.