# Starting counter of 50 questions per month?

Tags: support, specific-question

How do I check when my month ends? For Math stack exchange I recently got the 50 questions a month limit, just wondering how to check.

Comment: maybe not the best way but if you go into your profile's activity section and check the question list you have a list of 30 questions there and you can order them by newest (as in newest post). you can roughly see when you're getting close to 50 by looking to see where the first question of the month is and if it's on the second page you can assume you've posted between 31 and 50

Comment: If I were you, I'd take a step back and have a look at all of your questions. Could any of them have been solved with more research effort? Hitting the 50 question limit per month means that you've asked almost 2 questions a day, which is quite a lot. Sounds like you're relying too heavily on M.SE for answers.

Comment: Fwiw this is a reasonable general question, up until this moment info about the sliding window was rather buried and hard to find.

Comment: @angussidney To be honest most my questions are just homework checks, as you can see. I personally I'm never 100% sure if I'm right or not so I just post here so I should probably have more self confidence in myself if anything. I also lasted quite a while without even knowing about this 50 question limit until recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "end of month" date. It's a rolling check. So, you won't be able to ask new questions until you have fewer than 50 questions that are [30 days old or younger](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?m1=3&d1=31&y1=2017&type=sub&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=30&rec=).

So, in your [list of questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/408991/user349557?tab=questions&sort=newest), make sure they're sorted by "newest" and keep going back until you get to 30 days before today. You should also be able to work out when questions will start to "age out".

And, perhaps, you'll be more selective in asking questions in the future.

See also: [50 question per month limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/21960)